# Static class fields in construction

Tags: java, static

```
// package and import things..

public class A {

    public int x;

    public static A ob;

    A() {
        A.ob.x = 5;
    }

    public static void main(String args[) {
        A.ob = new A(); 
        System.out.println(ob.x);
    }
}
```

Why this code is give NullPointerException ? If i change "A.ob.x" to "this.x", it's done. But already A.ob = this in this code?

Comment: The assignment to `A.ob` will happen after the creation of A (after the constructor finishes), so while it is running `ob` is still null.

Comment: Step through this in a debugger to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A.ob = new A();
```

This first creates an A by executing the constructor, and then, assigns the created A to `A.ob`. It's basically equivalent to

```
A tmp = new A();
A.ob = tmp;
```

So, at the time the constructor is called, A.ob is still null. So you get a NullPointerException.